# Supporting a piece of 5 * 3 foot baltic birch plywood to prevent bending

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering

I'm working on converting a van to a nice living situation. This is my first post in the engineering forum; hopefully, I've gone into sufficient detail with adequate clarity.

In the back of the van, underneath the actual floor (the baltic birch), I have another floor (maple plywood, roughly 4 feet by 3 feet) that pulls out and will hook to the doors, such that one could sit/stand outside on the plywood (this moves on high density plastic because using drawer slides would take up too much room).

The issue is that with the weight (probably 300-400 lbs) on top of the floor (drawers filled with things, a small refrigerator), the plywood sags, such that I can't actually pull out the maple plywood because it is pinched between the baltic birch and the sub-floor).

The floor is currently held above the maple plywood (which slides in and out), by two pieces of 1/4inch angled aluminum on each side of the van, screwed into the struts of the van with three plus nuts (like rivets but much stronger).

I replaced the original floor with baltic birch, hoping that baltic birch would be stiff over the five feet across the van (baltic birch, I believe, has roughly 13 pieces of ply, where normal plywood has far fewer). Did not work. I then bought a piece of 1/2inch by 2inch aluminum, thinking that I could run that across (under the five foot piece of baltic birch) and would provide enough support to keep the baltic birch from sagging in the middle. That did not work either. Aluminum itself sagged under weight.

So my question is really what you can think of that would work in this situation. Ideally, it should be less than 1/2inch tall, since that is the clearance I left between the baltic birch ply and the maple ply. Would steel be stiff enough? It can be hollow or filled (I don't know that in this scenario filled will be much stiffer than hollow). Lighter the better because it's a van, but I doubt that anything with those dimensions will be substantially heavy, so that isn't a huge factor.

I could either bolt this piece of metal to the angled aluminum on each side...or I could stick weld it directly to the angled aluminum. I could, if necessary, also route a grove on the bottom of the baltic birch, to make room for thicker metal.

I called a local metal distributor and the employee told me they were not qualified to say anything about the stiffness of various metals.

Thanks much!

James

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this can work.

Comment: honesty you would do better at a handyman site or van life forum.  This isn't work that would be designed, it's work that would be built by people good with tools.  The people good with tools will be better at it than us engineers.

Comment: Appreciate the response. Isn’t it an engineering question though regarding whether steel would be stiff enough to support that weight without sagging…and whether that steel should be hollow or filled?

Comment: I guess, but these type of things are typically just best solved by doing.  That said, just via sniff-test, I'm with @r13.  I doubt anything with a dimension of 1/2 inches will work for you.  But maybe you need a re-design.  What about a center support that the underneath slider has a cutout to go around?  Creativity will probably be better than technical knowledge of strengths of materials

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; in this instance, the slider is underneath the maple plywood (which slides in and out), so I don't see how that would work, but I do agree with the idea of creativity. Perhaps in this instance, the best thing to do might be to route a grove in the bottom of the baltic birch, such that the dimensions of the steel can increase. So would .75 work? And here, I assume that steel will be stiffer than aluminum. Sorry to belabor what seem like technicalities.

Comment: but since I'd be cutting into finished wood and spending probably $40 on steel, it would really be nice to have some ballpark estimate of whether it would work. Maybe I should try to get in contact with a steel manufacturer...if this problem can't be solved mathematically?